# rdlc report in C#, ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, oracle10g

In report I have follwing Coloumns

```
TIN_Number,Period,Tax_pay,Tax_credited
```

i have period in 4 quater per year. for example If I am giving period between `200704` to `200903` than it is printing `200706,200709,200712,200803,200806,200809,200812,200903` for one TIN number on one row each having same TIN number. I want to seprate this period in quarter wise formate. i want to display sum of total tax_pay and Tax_credited as per quater per year.  please give me solution. thank u

Answer (score 0):

How you want your report is not really clear - why do you need TIN_Number in your data if you don't want to report against it?

Regardless, from whatever you have stated, you need to add group on `period` field and in group footer, add sum of tax_pay and tax_credited.

Comment: i am already grouping as per TIN number and if i am doing group by period than all period are splitting as month and yearwise

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field, named 'first_of_month'.  Assuming that the period is a string field, add the following to the formula's text:

```
//convert period to a date at the first of the month
//creating a date field gives you formatting flexibility.
Date({TABLE.period}[1 to 4], {TABLE.period}[5 to 6], 1)
```

Insert a group using the {@first_of_month} as its source.  Choose 'for each quarter' from the 'This section will be printed:" combobox.

Add summary fields to the group's footer section

Move group 'above'/'outside' the group on the TIN

** edit **

another option would be to create a 'quarter' formula and group on it.  The formula's text would be (again, assuming that it is a string):

```
//get month and convert to number
Numbervar MM := ToNumber({TABLE.period}[5 to 6]);

//calculate quarter
Ceiling(MM/3);
```

Comment: i dont want date formatting i want period only in "YYYYMM" formate. please suggest me answer

Comment: You can easily format a date field to 'YYYYMM' using the field's property inspector.

Comment: you have any idea about how to write rdlc custom code for the same, in custom code property window

Comment: What is 'RDLC'?  Are you hoping for VB syntax?  In the future, please add the relevant details to your question.

Comment: sorry craig...... i want VB syntax.....There is area to write custom code in RDLC, report -> Properties -> code.  can u help me???

Comment: i tryed using numbervar expression but it is giving error as unrecognized identifire